# Input devices stopped working during system upgrade

Tags: ubuntu

I was upgrading Ubuntu on my server (but Ubuntu is in desktop version) when mouse and keyboard stopped working :( So the screen went black (screensaver), and now I can't do anything. I don't know what stage of upgrade it stopped working, probably now it waits for me to answer some question.

Keyboard and mouse were connected by KVM, connecting them directly doesn't help. Both are on USB.

What I can do, is connecting to the machine by ssh. Can I somehow see and answer questions of update system and somehow finalize process of upgrade?

Comment: On a side note: why do you need a desktop installation on a server?

Comment: Well, it's not _only_ a server. It acts also as a machine I can always use for internet when I need to check something fast. Just because it's always on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH in, see if `who` will tell you what tty you were on, and see if you can snoop on it with `ttysnoop {tty}`.

Updated: It's not `watch` on Ubunto like I thought it was, it's `ttysnoop`.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks, but my watch doesn't seem like it has "-W" option. 
"watch -W 7" doesn't work, neither "watch -W tty7". Sorry for being such noob :)

Comment: Sorry for stumbling through this, but I don't use Linux. The command on Ubuntu is `ttysnoop` but it's not clear from the documentation if you can write to the tty through the snp driver; give it a try, I'm very curious to know now too.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
@amorfis: Did you have a Ubuntu desktop installation on the server? I once had the ubuntu server version installed, with the ubuntu-desktop on top of it. Upgrading (while booted in the desktop,via the update manager interface) hung my system as there was a package splash, which was essential for the desktop , but was removed during the update...

@chris S: Well, i installed ttysnoop on ubuntu and it seems like it has to be setup beforehand to snoop on particular devices before logging in...

Answer (score 1):

I too have run into this on update, but it turned out that the grub file (in /boot/grub/menu.lst) was booting the old Ubuntu 9.x kernel with the Ubuntu 10.04 drivers.

I fixed this by ssh-ing into a running system (with a dead/frozen console), manually added the correct kernel (look in /boot for the newest one) and rebooted. Note: the top system is the default one.